# How to flash something if the data partition is encrypted?

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, custom-roms, side-loading

## Problem

The data on my phone is encrypted and I do not know how to flash something without decrypting it by using `Disable Force Encryption`.
When the data partition is decrypted I can just copy a file to be flashed to data, boot to recovery and flash it via recovery. But if the data partition is encrypted I cannot find/flash that file in recovery

Comment: Disable Force Encryption cannot 'decrypt' your phone (see answer). TWRP / OrangeFox / Redwolf can (if maintainer has implemented right)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [TWRP](https://twrp.me/) (Recommended)

TWRP allows you to temporarily decrypt your data by using your phone's password

### Why is this solution recommended?

#### Flashing incidents

I was trying to uninstall NikGapps by renaming .zip file to `UnInstall.zip` as it is recommended, but for some reasons OrangeFox was doing something under the hood and NikGapps was not understanding that the zip file has `uninstall.zip` name and it must uninstall Gapps instead of installing. When I tried the same on TWRP everything was working. The same story was with Magisk uninstalling where I have to rename it to `uninstall.zip` too

#### Decryption

It is much harder to use your phone when you cannot go to recovery and flash something without a PC or Sd-Card

#### Magisk flash from OrangeFox (Inaccurate, possibly my fault)

When I tried the `Add magisk` feature from OrangeFox instead of flashing it manually I got bootloop. Possibly I have done something wrong and it is my fault. Please write in the comments if it is working fine and I will delete this story with magisk

---

## Sd-Card

If you move your files to Sd-Card and connect Sd-Card to your phone you will be able to flash the files that are located on in

---

## Adb sideload

1. Connect your phone to a PC with installed `adb`.
   *[How or where to install adb](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb)*
2. Reboot to recovery and enable `adb sideload` feature there.
   *How to open recovery? Disable your phone and hold Power button and Volume Down button. If it does not work find [how to open recovery on your phone](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+open+terminal)*
3. Execute `adb sideload PATH_TO_FLASHABLE_FILE` in your terminal/command line. *Do not forget to change `PATH_TO_FLASHABLE_FILE` to your real path.*
   *[How to open terminal](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+open+terminal&oq=how+to+open+terminal)*
4. See logs in your recovery and wait until it is successfully complete
   Congratulations. Your file is flashed without decrypting the data partition

Comment: @Robert, you said `You simply flash the system partition and hope that the new system can also decrypt the data partition.`, why do you think that is the thing I am doing? I was flashing files that I cannot just put in my storage and flash them via twrp so I showed how to do it by using adb sideload

Comment: "Your file is flashed on your encrypted ROM without decrypting it" this read like the ROM is encrypted which is not the case, the data partition is encrypted.

Answer (score 2):

First, let's clarify the terms 'decrypted' and 'unencrypted':

- When data on the phone is encrypted, one must (online) **de**crypt it with the proper PIN/pattern/password in order to access files.
- When encryption is disabled, data remains **un**encrypted. Only possible after formatting, (offline) access to plain files is possible.

The latter can be achieved with `Disable Force Encryption` but requires **formatting** (data loss). You don't need to decrypt userdata in TWRP recovery, you can just copy files to RAM or MicroSD Card via `adb`.

```
$ adb push ./no-verity-opt-encrypt-6.1.zip /tmp
$ adb shell twrp install /tmp/no-verity-opt-encrypt-6.1.zip
```

**Note:** this zip won't change the encryption state. In order to become **unencrypted**, factory reset or formatting is required (**WARNING: all data lost!**)

```
$ adb shell twrp format data
```

Comment: Wow! I have found out that encrypted data can be decrypted yesterday when installed TeamWin Recovery instead of OrangeFox. Thank you for information

Your solution with `adb shell twrp install` is excellent. I did not know that I can do such things if the data is encrypted

Comment: source https://twrp.me/faq/openrecoveryscript.html